# CSRF mismatch with Vue SPA and Laravel sanctum in production

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, laravel-sanctum

I have a vue SPA running on domain.co.uk and a laravel api running on api.domain.co.uk.

When I make a post request I get a CSRF mismatch error (419) because it isn't being sent in the header but instead as a cookie.

This is the code that sends the post request, using axios

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://api.domain.co.uk/';

export default class Api {
    constructor() {}

    async getCSRF() {
        return new Promise(async ( resolve, reject ) => {
            await axios.get( 'sanctum/csrf-cookie' )
            .then(( response ) => {
                resolve();
            }) 
            .catch(( error ) => {
                reject( error );
            })
        })
    }
    
    async login( email, password ) {
        return new Promise(async ( resolve, reject ) => {
            await axios.get( 'sanctum/csrf-cookie' ).then(( cookie ) => {
                await axios.post( 'login', { email: email, password: password } )
                .then(( response ) => {
                    resolve( response.data );
                })
                .catch(( error ) => {
                    reject( error.response.data );
                })
            })
            
        })
    }
}
```

I have set the session domain and stateful domains on the server. The env is

```
APP_URL=https://api.domain.co.uk
FRONTEND_URL=https://domain.co.uk
SESSION_DOMAIN=domain.co.uk
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=domain.co.uk
```

The getCSRF request is successful and the XSRF-TOKEN and laravel_session cookies are set. But in the request the X-SRF-TOKEN header is not sent.

It works locally with the same setup, SPA running on localhost:5173 and api on localhost:8000.

Extra - even if i manually set the header i still get a mismatch

Comment: `https://api.domain.co.uk` and `https://domain.co.uk` are different origins. Try please add to `config/cors.php` 'allowed_origins' your spa origin `https://domain.co.uk`. I believe it should help.

Comment: it is added, laravel adds it as the FRONTEND_URL env variable to cors